# Body voltage from stray capacitance

Tags: capacitor, ac, impedance, mains

I've been learning about stray capacitances in my electronics module and was trying to apply the concept. If I were to hold a mains wire, consisting of a live, neutral and ground, and there were stray capacitances of X Farads to each. What would this circuit look like? What would be the resulting voltage on my body, assuming I am in the UK with 240V live, and 50Hz. This is without taking into account other stray capacitances, and the insulation resistance would be very high.

Comment: If you hold a live cable, you already have X capacitance between each conductor and you via the plastic insulation. The resulting voltage on you is negligible due to your stray resistance to ground.

Comment: By negligible, we mean micro-volts or milli-volts.  Increase the surface area contact to the live wire insulation, and this increases the capacitance, which will increase the voltage.  If the stray resistance to ground is very high, could see tens or even hundreds of volts.  But since the coupling capacitance is still relatively small, negligible current would flow.

Answer (score 0):

For a two conductor mains cable it would look like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFtWHP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C_P and C_N are the capacitances from the phase and neutral to your hand. They form a voltage divider that has ~120 VAC at the center (when unloaded). The capacitance varies with conductor size, insulation thickness, and hand width (I measured 20 pF on an 80 mm length of 'figure 8' lamp cord).

C_body is the capacitance from your body to ground. The standard [human body model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-body_model) specifies 100 pF, but depending how much distance there is between you and mains ground it could be a lot lower (I measured ~50 pF when standing in socks on a carpeted concrete floor).

With the component values shown the voltage on the body should be ~53 VAC and 75 V peak. However the impedance at 50 Hz is very high. When measured with a meter or oscilloscope that has in input impedance of 10 MΩ it should read ~14 VAC or 20.5 V peak. I measured 20 V peak on my scope.

I also measured a three conductor 10 A rated grounded power cable and got 14 V peak on the scope. In this case the voltage is expected to be lower because the insulation is thicker and two of the conductors are connected to ground. Adjusting C_P and C_N in the simulator to match my measurement gives ~37 VAC and ~53 V peak without scope probe loading.